# VIM: Create a function to generate several lines of buffer

Tags: vim

I have about ninety configuration files that I need to add an almost identical block of additional code to, with only two instances of a single word differing each time. I would very much like to repeat as little effort as possible.

Is it possible, in VIM, to write a function that generates a block of text depending on an argument and either feeds it into the buffer or pastes it after the current cursor position? And if so, what documentation should I be looking into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) pretty much, it can be used to, for example, write `newconf`, press `Tab` which expands `newconf` to some specified template and places the caret in one position (and in the next ones by subsequent `Tab` presses).  Hart to explain, apparently [this video](http://vimeo.com/3535418) explains it (I guess, no plugin here).  Not sure if it's the best solution, but on the whole it's quite handy.

Maybe `sed`, `patch` or even [`Coccinelle`](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) ("semantic patching") might help, too.

Comment: Absolutely perfect for what I need. Thanks!

Comment: i think snipMate adds some nice functionality over what vim alone can do.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly from within VIM, by customizing your .vimrc file, too, using abbreviations.

in .vimrc:

```
:ab _mytxt ################################################################################^M# This is a comment^Mkey1=value1^Mkey2=value2^M#^Mecho "Hello, World!"^M################################################################################
```

in vi, in insert mode, just type `_mytxt`, and vim will automatically replace it with the unabbreviated text.

```
_mytxt
```

becomes

```
################################################################################
# This is a comment
key1=value1
key2=value2
#
echo "Hello, World!"
################################################################################
```

Just read up on the .vimrc file, and customizing it.  You can also look at customations for the .exrc file, which are often usable by VIM.

Comment: Also interesting, but I think snipMate's closer to what I need.